# #2002 - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Tags: mysql, sockets

I was trying to install something on a Ubuntu 14.04 machine, ran `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get upgrade` and it apparently did something to my MySQL server.

Now I can't start it. I get this error:

```
#2002 - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13) — 
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
```

I'm not sure if the server is even installed. When I try to restart or start the service it always returns "Job failed!".

I've purged everything:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql\*
```

and then tried to install it back with

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

but it basically ends with this and I'm back to square one.

```
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.5_5.5.35+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Aborting downgrade from (at least) 5.6 to 5.5.
If are sure you want to downgrade to 5.5, remove the file
/var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag and try installing again.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.35+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1


Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.35+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Trying to *install mysql-server-5.6* and *mysql-client-5.6* doesn't help either:

```
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up mysql-common-5.6 (5.6.16-1~exp1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.7) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.6
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've found so many posts here with the same error message and tried probably all the solutions proposed, but nothing works. Help!

## SOLVED

Though, perhaps not in the best way possible.
Here's what I did:

```
$ sudo -i
# sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql\* 
# cp -R /var/lib/mysql /home/user/backup
# sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/
# sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
# sudo apt-get autoremove
# sudo apt-get autoclean
# sudo apt-get install mysql-server php5-mysql
```

Then I had to restore my backed up databases and finally I got it up and running. I'm so mad at to how much time I lost to this.

Comment: two solutions : first the db server is not running, second the socket isent there. Take a look in the /etc/mysql/my.cnf where the socket is

Comment: The socket is in `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` according to the my.cnf file. Double checked and it really is there and belongs to the mysql user.

Comment: Try deleting the mysqld.sock and then restart mysql.

Comment: purge MySQL and install MariaDB. Its the better MySQL : see this https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/getting-installing-and-upgrading-mariadb/

Comment: @apesa Didn't help, unfortunately. But when I removed the */var/lib/mysql* directory and installed the server again, it started and now works. Can't believe how much time I've lost to that